# When is it necessary to use an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, subclass, abstract

I am fairly new to Java and haven't yet needed to use an abstract class. I understand that:

- Abstract classes can't be instantiated
- Abstract classes often have abstract methods
- Its purpose is only for other classes to extend

I also understand that abstract class can be used when you want to create new versions of your components. How does this work?

In what type of (specific) situation would it be beneficial to use abstract classes?

Also, I have read that you can use them to "partially implement your class." What exactly does this mean?

And my final question is, could extending a regular class achieve similar results?

Comment: I guess every search engine can answer this (too broad) question in minutes.

Comment: The JDK has a few abstract classes -- `AbstractList` comes to mind. It could be helpful to look at what they provide, and how sublasses use them.

Comment: @laune "every search engine" cannot provide the details for which I am asking, nor can they provide real situational examples like ppuskar's answer.

Comment: Did you try at least one, once? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96947/why-should-i-declare-a-class-as-an-abstract-class and so on and on.

Comment: @laune I did an appropriate amount of research and only asked this to clarify parts that I was unsure of. Is that against the rules here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In what type of (specific) situation would it be beneficial to use abstract classes?

You would want to use an abstract class when you want to provide some predefined methods in the base class without allowing the user to instantiate the base class as only more specific subclasses that define the rest of the behavior are good enough classes to stand alone and be used.

> Also, I have read that you can use them to "partially implement your class." What exactly does this mean?

It means you can if you want only declare methods (label them abstract), in which subclasses have to define them, while also being able to define methods in the abstract class that all subclasses can also make use of.

> And my final question is, could extending a regular class achieve similar results?

Only if the objects of the base class are useable by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You use an abstract class when a portion of your functionality is known, but a portion is variable.

```
public abstract class Channel {

  private Response response;

  public abstract void connect();

  public abstract void sendMessage(Message message);

  public abstract Response awaitResponse();

  public abstract void disconnect();

  public void send(Message message) {
    connect();
    sendMessage(message);
    response = awaitResponse();
    disconnect();
  }

  public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
  }

}
```

now you have a "communications channel" which you know you can send messages on, but have absolutely no idea of what the protocol is, how it connects, or how it handles the response.

To give an example of how far one might twist this idea.  Let's explore "email" channels.

```
public class EmailChannel extends Channel {

  public void connect() {
    ... open a SMTP socket to the email server ...
    ... open a HTTP socket for the response channel ...
  }

  public void sendMessage(Message message) {
    ... create a URL with encoding for the "response link" ...
    ... negotiate SMTP protocol ELHO, etc...
    ... send an email message with the "message" contents ...
    ... append the embedded HTTP "response link" ...
    ... close the SMTP socket ...
  }

  public Response awaitResponse() {
    ... wait till expected "GET" occurs on the HTTP socket ...
    ... return new Response(... details ...)
  }

  public void disconnect() {
    ... close the HTTP socket ...
  }
}
```

There are of course many actual issues with the code above, but it is an example of the Template pattern, and a decent example of why one might want to write an abstract class.

Abstract classes become even more valuable when you have more implementations of them.  To stretch our slapdash example just a bit further, imagine a system which offers a choice of protocols.

```
Contact "John Doe" by
1) email
2) SMS
3) chat
```

which would be backed by a

```
public Channel getChannelForInput(int value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 1: return new EmailChannel();
    case 2: return new SMSChannel();
    case 3: return new ChatChannel();
    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("value cannot be " + value);
  }
}
```

and that backing would fit into something like

```
...
Channel channel = getChannelForInput(value);
channel.send(message);
displayResponse(channel.getResponse());
...
```

Hopefully now you can see how it might be useful to have a type that guarantees certain behaviors while leaving some of the details unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

To add an example to @NESPowerGlove explaination.

Think of this scenario, you have a DAL(Data Access layer), Across all the DAO implementation classes you may be doing certain operation repeatedly, for e.g., opening connection, closing connection, logging specific task.
So these are the operation you can define in your abstract class(namely BaseDAO)
Now every DAOImpl which will extend BaseDAO just need to call methods define in your abstract class, for opening closing connection and logging too..

This is a very specific scenario, you'll find its usage at other places too

Answer (score 0):

I think for reading about `Abstract Classes`, [this link can help you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Since @NESPowerGlove has already answer some of your questions, so my answer will include only example, i will add details if you want.

Think of your self as an owner of pizza company (as well as keen programmer too :p). Now you have two branches in two different countries, say USA and Italy.
Since you know people of both countries have `different tastes`, so you are `customizing the pizza making process as per country's people taste`. That means. USA branch will serve pizza made as per USA style and Italian branch will serve pizza made in Italian style.

Since making of pizza is common in both processes, so you are defining an abstract class with an abstract method `makePizza()', method is marked abstract because you only know branches will make pizza, but how they will make pizza that is upto branch.

```
abstract class MyPizzaCompany{
  public asbtract void makePizza();
}
```

Since, US branch serves pizza made in US style, so USBrach class will give its own implementation(here process of making pizza) for making pizza.

```
class USBranch extends MyPizzaCompany{
    @Override
    void makePizza() {
        // make pizza in US style
    }
}
```

Similarly, for Italian branch

```
class ItalianBranch extends MyPizzaCompany{
    @Override
    void makePizza() {
        // make pizza in italian style
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a scenario where you are writing a class. You write logic into methods that you know at that time and declare few methods abstract whose logic will be added by sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

We should create Abstract Class when we have following requirement

1. You want to have some common functionality for all sub classes
2. There must be some implementation required in each sub class as per different requirements
3. You want to deal between subtypes with abstract class object reference. (Polymorphism)